# How to find the highest value of a sub-string ending in integer in Python?

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

How to find the highest value of a sub-string ending in integer in Python?

Input:

```
a =  """ classification-filters {
     filter123 {
     filter025 {
     filter0 { """
```

Output: sub-string ending with the largest integer = "filter123"

Comment: what have you tried so far? Is this the only format you are coming across? This looks like hiearchel text what format is it, maybe there is a parse for it?  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

a =  """ classification-filters {
    filter123 {
    filter025 {
    filter0 { """

filters = re.findall(r'(filter(\d+))', a)
largest = max(tup[1] for tup in filters)
for filter in filters:
    if filter[1] == largest:
        print(filter[0])
```

Alternatively, the list of results could be sorted and the last element could then be printed:

```
filters = re.findall(r'filter\d+', a)
filters.sort()
print(filters[-1]
```